# Is using pip from conda environment folder the same as using that pip executable directly?

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

Is running

```
conda activate -n myenv
pip install mypackage
```

equivalent to running

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip install mypackage
```

?

Comment: Yes, though you could probably mess it up either advertently or inadvertently if you are messing with paths. If you want to be really sure you can always run python -m pip from the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, they are effectively the same because Conda environment activation prepends the environment's `bin/` directory to PATH and therefore the former will evaluate to the latter.

However, it may be noted that were some non-standard manipulation of PATH or pip-relevant environment variables carried out by [activation scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/activate-scripts.html) then there could be a difference. But this is only a note about *possibilities*, not something encountered in typical use.